# MPI Scatter and Gather not working for 1d array

Tags: c++, mpi, cluster-computing

I am trying to run a hybrid MPI/OpenMP job on a cluster where each node initiate a MPI task and OpenMP uses all the cpu cores of that node. The code works perfectly fine on my computer, but it is showing such error while running on cluster:

*select.c:434  UCX  ERROR no active messages transport to : posix/memory - Destination is unreachable, sysv/memory - Destination is unreachable, self/memory - Destination is unreachable, sockcm/sockaddr - no am bcopy, rdmacm/sockaddr - no am bcopy, cma/memory - no am bcopy*

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int size;
    int rank;

    double *global_var = NULL;
    double local_var[5];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); 
      
    if(rank == 0){
        t_1 = std::time(0);
        cout << "number of MPI processes: " << size << endl;
        cout << "number of maximum possible threads: "<< omp_get_max_threads()<<endl;

        global_var = new double[5*size];              
    }

    MPI_Scatter(global_var, 5, MPI_DOUBLE, &local_var, 5, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

    execute_function_here();

    MPI_Gather(&local_var, 5, MPI_DOUBLE, global_var, 5, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize(); 

    if(rank == 0){
      //do something with gathered array
        delete [] global_var;
    } 
   return 0;
}
```

I am using intel compiler and intel mpi.

Comment: This sounds like it's not a problem with your code, and instead with the installation of MPI on this cluster. Are you sure that it is installed and configured correctly on the target cluster?

Comment: Hey, thanks! I just ran my job with mvapich2 instead of intel mpi and the job ran just fine.